# Import Eclipse Code Template .xml file to IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, import, code-templates

My team is using Eclipse but I would like to use IntelliJ. They have this Code Template .xml file which they import into Eclipse, but I haven't found a way to import this in IntelliJ, how should I do it?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates>
   <template autoinsert="true" context="setterbody_context" deleted="false" description="Code in created setters" enabled="true" id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.codetemplates.setterbody" name="setterbody">${field} = ${param};</template>
</templates>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

If you insist on using a different tool than the rest of your team, you'll have to manage it manually. If you absolutely have to do this, I suppose you should just inspect each result of the formatting guidelines and implement that in an IntelliJ formatter.